# Running vite-electron with express backend

Tags: node.js, express, electron

I have created an Electron app using vite-electron with an Express server in the backend.
This is only a hello world application, but there is a problem with running the server and Electron together.

The front-end files are located inside the main directory and the server files are located in the main directory in a subdirectory called "server"

**Here is the package.json**

```js
{

  "name": "app",

  "version": "2.0.0",

  "type": "module",

  "main": "dist-electron/main/index.js",

  "private": true,

  "keywords": [

    "electron",

    "rollup",

    "vite",

    "vue3",

    "vue"

  ],

  "debug": {

    "env": {

      "VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL": "http://127.0.0.1:3344/"

    }

  },

  "scripts": {

    "dev:frontend": "vite",

    "dev:backend": "nodemon server/index.js",

    "dev": "concurrently 'npm:dev:frontend' 'npm:dev:backend'",

    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build && electron-builder",

    "preview": "vite preview"

  },

  "devDependencies": {

    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.1.0",

    "concurrently": "^8.0.1",

    "electron": "^24.1.3",

    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",

    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",

    "typescript": "^5.0.2",

    "vite": "^4.1.4",

    "vite-plugin-electron": "^0.11.2",

    "vite-plugin-electron-renderer": "^0.14.1",

    "vue": "^3.2.47",

    "vue-tsc": "^1.2.0"

  },

  "dependencies": {

    "express": "^4.18.2",

    "i": "^0.3.7",

    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0"

  }

}
```

I only imported the index.js from the server in the Electron index.ts file.
I still receive this message:
index.js is treated as an ES module as it is a.js file whose nearest parent package.json
contains "type": module which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES

Any suggestion is appreciated!
Thanks